# Grails: can i switch case database url

Tags: database, grails, datasource

How can i do sth like this in Grails 2.0.4?

```
dataSource {

        dbCreate = "create-drop"
        String host = request.getServerName()
        switch( host ) {
            case "company1.com": url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db1"
            case "company2.com": url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db2"
            default: null
        }
}
```

i don't want to use multi-tenant-core plugin

Comment: Well, did it work? If not, why not?

Comment: I don't think you can connect to arbitrary databases at run time this way.. neither your closure will get called for every incoming request.

Answer (score 4):

Grails 2 supports [multiple datasources](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#multipleDatasources) so you should configure two separate data sources and let your service/domain layer do the switch between the two:

```
dataSource_company1 {
    dbCreate = "create-drop"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db1"
}
dataSource_company2 {
    dbCreate = "create-drop"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db2"
}
```

Then configure your domain objects to support both:

```
class Foo {
    static mapping = {
        datasources(['company1', 'company2'])
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then finally, use datasource based on request:

```
def company = request.serverName.split('.')[0]
def fooThings = Foo."$company".findAll()
```

You can also autowire your data sources into your services or controllers and use them directly.

Comment: Hi @krock, thanks for your answer.

Can you suggest me in case

if i have 10 domains and 10 queries per 1 domain

do i have to use Domain."$company".findAll() 100 times

is there any way that simpler?

Comment: findAll() was just an example of being able to use the standard gorm static methods after specifying a dataSource.  You should use findBy, criteria or HQL queries to retrieve relevant data.  You should also consider caching if you are always retrieving the same unchanging data.